# How can I add a google extension to python selenium driver?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use a extension in Selenium but can't seem to find the solution for this. This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_extension('/Downloads/extension.crx')

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Downloads/chromedriver", options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1600, 1200)
```

It gives the following error: failed to load extension from: /downloads/extension.crx. Manifest is unreadable or missing.

Comment: How did you compile your chrome extension? I think you did not include your manifest.json while compiling your chrome extension

Comment: I used: https://crxextractor.com/ to download the extension from chrome.google.com

Comment: Can you specify the name of the extension so that i could try.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hotspot-shield-vpn-free-p/nlbejmccbhkncgokjcmghpfloaajcffj?hl=en